# Set drawable to the end of the text, in TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to set the drawable image to the end of the text but it shows the end of the text view.

**Here is my code**

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_overweight_messsage"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_marginVertical_Large"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="dvdmnvkdnxknb vcnbvcxmnbxm,cbn,m vnnxmndxvbhddbv svbhzv"
     android:textColor="@color/required"
     android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_small"
     android:drawablePadding="@dimen/widget_padding"
     android:drawableRight="@drawable/img_infobn"
     android:visibility="gone"
     app:mfafont="@string/font_Questrial_Regular"
     tools:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: You can add details like screenshot of your current UI and expected UI for us to have a clear picture

Comment: Use [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan) instead . Compound Drawable will always show either of 4 edges so you need to add icon to the text in this case .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can embed an [`ImageSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan) in a [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) and set the [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) to display that. For example:

```
String text = "hello  ";
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.my_icon);
sb.setSpan(imageSpan, text.length() - 1, text.length()), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(sb);
```

Comment: if i am taking text.length(), text.length() + 1 then getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (80 ... 81) ends beyond length 80

Comment: text.length()-1 , text.length() this is work for me but there is no space between text and icon. i want single space between them

Comment: Yes you could add another space at the end of text.

Comment: added two space after text , got my solution , thank you so much @jspcal

Answer (score -1):

Try setting

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `android:drawableEnd` instead of `drawableRight`.

Answer (score -2):

Check this -

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="text"/>
```

Comment: This will put at the end of the text view not text itself, please read the question first.